# Django runserver and makemigration fail with trace showing older migration

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-migrations

I added a field to a model this evening and when I ran makemigrations it told me the field didn't exist. I noticed a previous migration was referenced in the trace. I tried adding another field to a different model and makemigrations worked fine.

Not only did makemigrations fail, but runserver was also failing. Both with a previous migration, #37 in the trace. I was attempting to generate migration #40. I manually created migration number 40, put my field in models.py, and ran migrate successfully. Runserver then worked fine as well.

I'm trying to get to the bottom of understanding why this previous migration is causing new makemigrations in that model and runserver to fail. I have worked around the problem by creating the migration script manually, but it worries me that a previous migration is causing this. Why is a new makemigration attempt erring due to the exact field I'm attempting to add not existing?

```
# Note: Model2 also happens to be my app name and I may have mistakenly put Model2 where I should have put app name. Since I'm struggling to read what is going on, I wasn't sure. 
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x1077b3e60>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/my-user-name/.virtualenvs/my-project-name/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 222, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/my-user-name/.virtualenvs/my-project-name/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 107, in inner_run
    self.check_migrations()
  File "/Users/my-user-name/.virtualenvs/my-project-name/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 159, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
  File "/Users/my-user-name/.virtualenvs/my-project-name/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 17, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/Users/my-user-name/.virtualenvs/my-project-name/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 48, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/Users/my-user-name/.virtualenvs/my-project-name/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 173, in build_graph
    self.load_disk()
  File "/Users/my-user-name/.virtualenvs/my-project-name/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 103, in load_disk
    migration_module = import_module("%s.%s" % (module_name, migration_name))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/my-user-name/Code/my-project-name/my-app/migrations/0037_auto_20150824_0114.py", line 8, in <module>
    class Migration(migrations.Migration):
  File "/Users/my-user-name/Code/my-project-name/my-app/migrations/0037_auto_20150824_0114.py", line 32, in Migration
    field=models.ForeignKey(default=model1_model2_through.objects.all()[0].pk, to='model2.model1_model2_through'),
  File "/Users/my-user-name/.virtualenvs/my-project-name/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 177, in __getitem__
    return list(qs)[0]
  File "/Users/my-user-name/.virtualenvs/my-project-name/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 141, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/Users/my-user-name/.virtualenvs/my-project-name/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 966, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "/Users/my-user-name/.virtualenvs/my-project-name/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 265, in iterator
    for row in compiler.results_iter():
  File "/Users/my-user-name/.virtualenvs/my-project-name/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 700, in results_iter
    for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
  File "/Users/my-user-name/.virtualenvs/my-project-name/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 786, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/my-user-name/.virtualenvs/my-project-name/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 81, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/my-user-name/.virtualenvs/my-project-name/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/my-user-name/.virtualenvs/my-project-name/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/Users/my-user-name/.virtualenvs/my-project-name/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column model2_model1_model2_through.test_boolean does not exist
LINE 1: ...nt_date", "model2_model1_model2_through"."deposit_date", "model2_model1...


class Model1(models.Model):
    tours = models.ManyToManyField( 'Model2', through='Model1_Model2_Through')
    ...
class Model2(models.Model):
    ...
class Model1_Model2_Through(models.Model):
    test_boolean = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A previous migration, number 37 in this case, had a queryset used to calculate default values. Makemigrations runs through previous migrations, and because of this your queryset code in the earlier migration may cause the future makemigrations attempt to fail because of the fields that do not exist at the earlier point in time.

Instead of doing something like this in your migration.

```
SomeModel.objects.all()
```

You should do something like this, specifying only fields actually available at that migration.

```
SomeModel.objects.all().only('field1', 'field2', 'field3')
```